# On the same findByIdAndUpdate, use $push and $pull

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the code below I am trying to `findByIdAndUpdate` and for updating I want to add to two arrays of `objectIds` and pull from another. However, only the first command for the update is being executed. So `$push: {Group1: groupId, Group2: groupId}` is being executed but `$pull: {Group3: groupId}` is not.

**Is there a way to make both operations work together?**

**Code**

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    userId,
    {

        $push: {Group1: groupId, Group2: groupId},
        $pull: {Group3: groupId},
    },
    {'new': true, 'multi':true},
    function (err, user) {

        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Success.'
            });
        }

    }
);
```

**Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

//user schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: {type: String, required: true, index:{unique:true}},
   phoneNumber: {type: String, required: true, index:{unique:true}},
   password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
   name: String,
   Group1: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
   Group2: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
   Group3: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

here is the json representation on the User object

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('564a4a24f63d409f526659c4'),
"password": "$2a$10$YYEdr4kavrB2w8dRWHqWC.hAUd1pRzKM6YQt9iLtkrLDk0cRg24Wa",
"phoneNumber": "222",
"username": "222",
"Group1": [
    ObjectId('564a2ac4e982c8bb5122a96e')
],
"Group2": [],
"Group3": [],
"__v": 0
}
```

when I execute my code the json object looks like

```
    {
"_id": ObjectId('564a4a24f63d409f526659c4'),
"password": "$2a$10$YYEdr4kavrB2w8dRWHqWC.hAUd1pRzKM6YQt9iLtkrLDk0cRg24Wa",
"phoneNumber": "222",
"username": "222",
"Group1": [
    ObjectId('564a2ac4e982c8bb5122a96e')
],
"Group2": [
    ObjectId('564a2acae982c8bb5122a970')
],
"Group3": [
    ObjectId('564a2acae982c8bb5122a970')
],
"__v": 0
}
```

So the objectID from Group3 is not being removed. 
My thought on the matter was that i am not using the correct findByIdAndUpdate correctly when it comes to doing a pull and a push at the same time. 
This makes me lean towards just using a findById and then doing the update in the callback. Would there be a disadvantage in doing that vs using findByIdAndUpdate?

Comment: That should work. Can you edit your question to show your schema and the document you're updating?

Comment: Thank you for the response,  I added the Schema for the object that is being updated.

Comment: Thanks, can you also add the document being updated and the value of `groupId`?

Comment: The document being updated is the user schema and I don't know the group Id it should be any number.

Comment: No, I mean the JSON representation of the specific document you're updating where this isn't working.

Comment: Okay I updated the post to represent the speciffic json. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand...the doc after the update (presumably the second one) shows that you've added an element to `Group3` in the update and `Group1` didn't change.